# Delete a folder if it exists and write it as a new

Tags: android, file, save, directory

I have this code to create a folder:

```
 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Naruto Generation/");
                boolean success = false;
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    success = folder.mkdirs();
                }
                if (!success) {
                } else {
                }



                File direct = new File("/sdcard/Naruto Generation/");

                if (!direct.exists()) {
                    direct.mkdirs();
                }
```

Now I want to change it, and create the folder but if the folder exists delete it and write it as a new.

how can I do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove a directory you have to remove all its content:

for instance:

```
if (folder.isDirectory()) {
   File[] children = folder.listFiles();
   for (File child : children) {
      child.delete();
   }

   folder.delete();
}
```